# Should super().__str__() in Brython return something different?

Tags: python, brython

I ran across a weird situation using Brython and inheritance with the **str** method.  Here's my test using the [Brython console](https://brython.info/console.html):

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "A __str__ output."
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return super().__str__() + " (from B)"
... 
>>> x = A()
>>> x
<__main__.A object>
>>> y = B()
>>> y
<__main__.B object>
>>> str(y)
"<super: <class 'B'>, <B object>> (from B)"
```

I was expecting that last line to return:

```
"A __str__ output. (from B)"
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: bu reported in https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/issues/1366  , and fixed in 

Fixed in https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/commit/35d0a51aac5b0e69f5fa817033d12f4b4fd843d8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same code works fine in CPython, so it's probably a Brython bug.

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Dec 30 2019, 19:38:26)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "A __str__ output."
...
>>> class B(A):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return super().__str__() + " (from B)"
...
>>> x = A()
>>> x
<__main__.A object at 0x1048de590>
>>> y = B()
>>> y
<__main__.B object at 0x1048de790>
>>> str(y)
'A __str__ output. (from B)'
>>>
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case.  The tool I'm using uses Brython, so I can't just switch over.

Comment: Best report this as a bug then. https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/issues

Comment: Issue submitted: https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/issues/1366  Thanks for the link.

Comment: The maintainer lready  addressed the issue and commited a fix in https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/commit/35d0a51aac5b0e69f5fa817033d12f4b4fd843d8

Answer (score -1):

It's not neccessarily a bug, it could also be implementation-specific behaviour. The behaviour of super() function has changed in Pyhton too so you would have to make sure to use the right form, and to test against a compatible implementation.

What is happening in your case is that *you are printing a string representation of the proxy object returned by `super()`* instead of *calling `__str__` on the actual parent object*.

See here for more: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: This is a good point.  My local Python version is 3.6.9.  Is there a better way to call the super class's version of __str__?

Comment: No, super() is the right way to go, but you might have to add a parameters base class and/or instance, like in `super(A).__str__()` (check the docs, I'm not sure).

Comment: I don't think this is implementation-specific. Not being able to call an upstream `__str__` method would break the very use case for which `super` was created.

Comment: Adding explicit arguments to `super` doesn't help, so it's not just an issue of the magic argument-supplying behavior being broken.

Comment: What happens if you try to call another method using super, such as `def my_str(self): return self.__str__()` and try to call `super().my_str()` or `super(A).my_str()`? Does this work?

Comment: If it works with other methods, but not just with `__str__`, it smells like a bug indeed. The workaround should be trivial, but for all future generations try to at least report it.

Comment: it is a bug. This use case of super() is trivial, docuemnted, and deterministic.  -1